# efficient way to convert iterable to list of entity

Tags: java, list, java-stream, iterable, collectors

Whats an efficient way to convert iterable to list of entity?
in below code. last line which collects to list - take ~70seconds for large data set (about 400k)

```
//mongoDB: reading from collection
Iterable<SomeEntity> records = someSummaryCollection.find(and(
                geoWithin("geoLocation", BasicDBObject.parse(area)),
                lte(START_DATE, endDate),
                gte(END_DATE, startDate),
                ne(NAME, "testing"),
                nin(CATEGORIES, "random")
        )).maxTime(someDuration, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

//converting to list
List<SomeEntity> someSummary = StreamSupport.stream(records.spliterator(), true).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

note: we have a valid use-case where we need to fetch this volume of data and then do some business logic and show it in a UI

Comment: The UI is going to display four hundred thousand records at once? Most applications would display a subset of results and allow users to page through them.

Comment: right, but we are not showing 400k records at once. we are doing some business logic and dividing into different objects and returning them separately. but this is sort of a bottleneck where we need to fetch this data efficiently

Answer (score 1):

> Whats an efficient way to convert iterable to list of entity? in below code. last line which collects to list - take ~70seconds for large data set (about 400k)

The most efficient approach would probably be to just not.  Work with the `Iterable` and its iterator directly instead of converting to a `List`.

If that's not sufficient, and if you have a way to get the number of elements without iterating them all, and if a read-only `SequentialList` would be suitable for your purposes, then it shouldn't be too hard to create a suitable `ListIterator` wrapper for your iterators, and to use that and `AbstractSequentialList` to create a custom `List` wrapper that is very quick to instantiate.  *However*, I anticipate that it would take about as much time to fully iterate an instance of such a list as your streams-based approach takes to collect all the items.

But if you need a modifiable list or one featuring efficient random access,  then you'll need to iterate all the items once to build it, just as your stream approach does.  That's very likely what is taking most of the time.  But you could test that via something like this:

```
List<SomeEntity> someSummary = new ArrayList<>();  // or perhaps LinkedList
for (SomeEntity entity : records) {
    someSummary.add(entity);
}
```

That may also be advisable if you plan on iterating the elements multiple times, or if the original data have limited persistence (such as a database `ResultSet` might have).

Any way around, I think your underlying performance issue is most likely that it is costly to iterate all the elements of of the original iterable.  You may be able to make that a bit better, or at least less noticeable, but if you need in any case to iterate at least once through all the elements then you're unlikely to get a dramatic improvement no matter what you do.

Comment: Yeah I would guess that it’s the database query itself that is taking most of the time. There might be opportunities to optimize that, by ensuring that there is an appropriate index, for example.

Comment: A `ListIterator` supports backward traversal. So I don’t see, how you could implement a `List` atop an `Iterator` which only supports forward traversal. And you surely do not want to use `LinkedList` for 400k elements. Rather, specify an initial capacity to the `ArrayList`…